# Writing a CRON tab for windows and linux programatically only, without using any application

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, cron

I am trying to create a **CRON JOB** or **Schedule Task**(for Windows).

I searched over net and found several tutorials, But ended up with lot of confusion.

Some try to explain using a **Cpanel**, some use a **Task Scheduler**. As a developer what if i don't have direct access to **Cpanel** or **SSH**. Is there any method which programmatically executes the cron command.

I just want to know In-order to execute my php script(Script which delivers push messages) using a CRON, **Where should i give the command**

```
* * * * * /usr/php/php.exe /root/push.php
```

Also i found some uses vi editor, Actually its for UNIX.

I want to test the cron job initially on my localhost (XAMPP, windows machine), Later on my company's server(Windows) and finally on Clients Server(usually a LINUX based).

Comment: Is there any reason you can't test the script manually before deploying it to a Linux server? If you're in a Windows environment, just create a Scheduled task that runs the PHP file. And, it does not make any sense to use a ".exe" file in a crontab entry -- which is Linux.

Comment: do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: @DavidS Yeah i tested my script manually and the notifications are sent. This is how i tested. I just called my php script in the browser. But this is not i need! Instead the script should be called upon itself with out users action.

Comment: @Amir No i dint have the access

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a scheduled task in windows you must go trough the control panel. No other option.
When you want to create a cronjob. (only unix based) use:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and paste this command in there.

```
* * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/push.php
```

This job wil run every minute.